# Summary table counting unique entries independently of other variables

Tags: r

Using the example data frame `df` below:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                 Color=c("red", "green", "red", "red", "blue", "red"),
                 Size=c("s", "s", "m", "m", "s", "m"),
                 Country=c("UK", "US", "US", "US", "AUS", "CA")) %>% 
dplyr::arrange(across(everything()))

df
  ID Color Size Country
1  A green    s      US
2  A   red    s      UK
3  B   red    m      US
4  C  blue    s     AUS
5  C   red    m      CA
6  C   red    m      US
```

I summarize the number of `ID` elements per `Color` as well as per `Size` and `Country` in the following format using the `tableby` function from the `arsenal` package:

```
library(arsenal)

tableby(Color ~ Size + Country, df, test=F, total=F) %>% 
summary()
|                      | blue (N=1) | green (N=1) | red (N=4) |
|:---------------------|:----------:|:-----------:|:---------:|
|**Size**              |            |             |           |
|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;m   |  0 (0.0%)  |  0 (0.0%)   | 3 (75.0%) |
|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s   | 1 (100.0%) | 1 (100.0%)  | 1 (25.0%) |
|**Country**           |            |             |           |
|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AUS | 1 (100.0%) |  0 (0.0%)   | 0 (0.0%)  |
|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CA  |  0 (0.0%)  |  0 (0.0%)   | 1 (25.0%) |
|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UK  |  0 (0.0%)  |  0 (0.0%)   | 1 (25.0%) |
|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;US  |  0 (0.0%)  | 1 (100.0%)  | 2 (50.0%) |
```

However, I do not obtain the count of unique `ID` values per co-factor independently of the other (e.g. there are only 2 unique `ID` - `B` and `C` - with color `red` and size `m`, although there are indeed 3 rows with color `red` and size `m`).
Is there a way to achieve this task?

Comment: But you are doing a group by Size, and Country

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to (1) group Color by Size, (2) Color by Country independently, then (3) obtain a tableby format.

Comment: If it is independent, then you may need a loop `map(c("Size", "Country"), ~ tableby(reformulate(.x, response = 'Color'), df, test = FALSE, total = FALSE) %>% summary)`